# Silverlight 5: Create an overlay above child window

Tags: c#, button, overlay, silverlight-5.0, childwindow

I want to add a custom loading indicator when a button on child window is clicked. The loading overlay should appear above the whole screen. For this, I have created an overlay in rootvisual page which is hidden initially. When a button on child window is clicked, I make that overlay visible, but the problem is, the overlay appears behind the child window. What should I do to make it visible above child window? Is there any approach better than one I am using?

Comment: is there something like model window? perhaps that can be beneficial here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could create overlay without having to use something like Modal Window or another Child Window. I created one `div` occupying whole screen and containing loading.gif. The `div` is hidden initially (`display:none`) While I want to show loading indicator, I make that `div` visible through Silverlight code as shown below:

```
HtmlElement div = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("loading-overlay");
div.RemoveStyleAttribute("display");
```

To hide the loading indicator again,

```
HtmlElement div = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("loading-overlay");
div.SetStyleAttribute("display", "none");
```